# Share same domain for wp-admin but for different website

Tags: wp-admin, urls, security, ssl

I have site like

- `http://www.foo.com`
- `http://www.bar.com`

And I've a wildcard SSL cert `*.example.com`, instead of buying two SSL certs for the above two domains, can I re-use my existing wildcard SSL cert for wp-admin?

e.g.

- `http://foo.example.com`
- `http://bar.example.com`

Only for `wp-admin` for better security, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this and it does not matter if plugins are different for the two sites, as you are not not using the same tables or anything.

Still, if you use plugins that are badly written and build resource urls on top the home url, these will have issues (404 errors mostly).

Answer (score 1):

You don't say if is a multisite installation or two separate stand-alone ones.

I'm going to suppose it isn't multisite because if so, the answer is trivial. In the other case, there isn't any problem. You have to configure ssl as usual in your apache vhost or nginx for each domain with your wilcard certificate.

Aditionally, you can use the [Wordpress HTTPS plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/) to enable SSL only for wp-admin in each site (note that this plugin works in multisite also)

You'll have to use the [HTTPS domain alias](http://wordpress.org/plugins/https-domain-alias/) plugin, if you don't want to install multisite.

Answer (score 0):

if they use the same plugins I see no problem.

you can use up even as symbolic link, getting simpler to maintain and update

Comment: "Symbolic link" is one linux-path to another, not one domain to another.

Comment: Of course it is if both domains is in the same server

Comment: Right, but that won't be the case many times.

Answer (score 0):

Try the beauty of multisite feature of wordpress. Here are some tutorial links:

- [Create a Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)
- [Wordpress Multisite](http://premium.wpmudev.org/manuals/wordpress-multisite/)
- [Wordpress Multisite Guide](http://wpmu.org/wordpress-multisite-guide/)
- [Wordpress MU and Multisite](http://premium.wpmudev.org/manuals/wpmu-manual-2/wordpress-wordpress-mu-and-wordpress-multisite/)
- [Beginner Guide Wordpress Multisite](http://mashable.com/2012/07/26/beginner-guide-wordpress-multisite/)

So, guess your main site is `http://example.com`. Create two subsites:

1. http://foo.example.com
2. http://bar.example.com

As you have wildcard SSL so both subsites should be accessed with `https://`

Now, use a domain mapping plugin. WPMU DEV has a popular one. With that, you can map `http://foo.example.com` to `http://foo.com` and `http://bar.example.com` to `http://bar.com`

And you can access their admin by `https://example.com/wp-admin` or `https://foo.example.com/wp-admin` etc.

Comment: Multisite isn't really intended to be for two standalone sites. We'd need more context to know if OP should use it or not. http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network

Answer (score 0):

Setting up MultiSite in one main domain, that you have SSL, and then use the other domain as custom sunrise domain settings. You have to setup the .htaccess or vhost(for NGiNX) though. But both site will need to have almost same type domain or plugin. Its one way.

Other will be a bit complex one. I would setup two separate WordPress in two separate subdomain. Then from the vhost file I will point other root domain also to that same sub domain's root folder. You will need some tweaking in vhost or .htaccess to dynamically rewriting domain, and also hardcode home and home directory url from wp-config.php. Its far more complex process, might need some trial and error testing.

BTW I hope you know you could even buy a SSL certificate as low at just $10 USD, and if you use service like CloudFlare, now even in their free package they provide free SSL support. Though its not actually true SSL, but might serve purpose for normal low-end need.

Answer (score -1):

To enable the Network Setup menu item, you must first define multisite in the wp-config.php file.

Open up wp-config.php and add this line above where it says

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */.
```

If it doesn't say that anywhere, then add the line somewhere above the first line that begins with require or include:

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
```

You will need to refresh your browser to continue.

Comment: Please don't use this site to spam. Advertising links is not allowed. I have removed the link. Please refrain from posting irrelevant links. Thank you

Comment: I have asked you not to spam, I have now flagged this as spam. Continuous spamming will lead to your account being banned. I again ask, please refrain from this

Comment: The question had nothing to do with setting up multisite